# How can I spy on TouchableNativeFeedback onPress in React Native with @testing-library/react-native?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native

Help me please...

I have a React Native custom Button component that receives an onPress prop and passes that onPress to a TouchableNativeFeedback. I make a unit testing with @testing-library/react-native. I try to spy on onPress, to check if it is triggered when the TouchableNativeFeedback is touched. Somehow the spy function is not called when I simulate press event on the Button. Is there any mistake in my implementation?

FI: This behavior only occurs in TouchableNativeFeedback, but working perfectly with Button

Here is my implementation:

Button.js

```js
const Button = ({onPress, label}) => (
  <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={onPress} testID="button">
    <View style={someStyling}>
      <Text>{label}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
)

export default Button
```

Button.test.js

```js
  it("Fire onPress props when button pressed", () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();

    const { getByTestId } = render(<Button onPress={mockFn} />);
    const button = getByTestId("button");
    
    fireEvent.press(button);
    
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a component using `<TouchableNativeFeedback/>`. My test case failed with a message saying *No instances found* on the `getByText` call.

After few attempts, I used following snippet for debugging:

```
const { debug } = render(<Tag onPress={handler}>Press me</Tag>);
debug();
```

Along with some other details, following message popped up in console:

`TouchableNativeFeedback is not supported on this platform!`

At this moment, there is a related thread regarding `Touchable*` components on [react-native-testing-library GH issues](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/28) where they explain details and provide some workarounds.

I ended up using platform detection in my component, as that's what I wanted to do anyway:

```
const TouchComponent =
  Platform.OS === 'android' ? TouchableNativeFeedback : TouchableOpacity;

return (
  <TouchComponent onPress={onPress}>
    ...
  </TouchComponent>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

What solved it for me was that fact that my `TouchableXXX` component was imported from
`react-native-gesture-handler`. This library probably was imported as `dependency` by one of my dependecies. I guess when I wrote `TouchableXXX` it was imported automatically from there by my IDE.
After changing the `import` statement to import from `react-native` - everything worked for me in tests.
So eventually my change was from this:

```js
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

to this

```js
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
```